# Not getting application context in JMS listner non activity class android

Tags: java, android, jms, android-notifications

I am new to android and I am receiving the message in Android using jms topic now I want to generate notification of that message, For example as message is received notification appears. For generating notification, I need context of the application I tried different ways but not working can anybody now how to get the context in message listener. My listener implementation and notification function

**Message Listener**

```
    private class DestinationMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {

                System.out.println(message);
                Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
                sendNotification("Helo","title",1,"test");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //logMessage("EXCEPTION: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Notification Class**

```
public void sendNotification(String title, String msg, int msgId, String badge,Context ctx) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent tabsIntent = new Intent(ctx, TabsFragmentActivity_.class);
    tabsIntent.putExtra("GO_TO_MESSAGES", true);
    tabsIntent.putExtra("MSG_ID", msgId);
    tabsIntent.putExtra(TabsFragmentActivity.BADGE_KEY, badge);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, tabsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

    mNotificationManager.notify(msgId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

**Note:**
I am not receiving context in message listener implementation and this class is a non-activity class.I am using android annotation framework.

Answer (score 1):

@Awais: you have to pass context to non activity/receiver/service class. You can also have other option like defining an application class in your application package and through this application package you can have appliction context.
In Android Manifest file declare following

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">

</application>
```

then write the class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

private class DestinationMessageListener implements MessageListener {

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {

            System.out.println(message);
            Context ctx = MyApplication.getAppContext();
            sendNotification("Helo","title",1,"test",ctx);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //logMessage("EXCEPTION: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are accessing MyApplication getAppContext() method, it always return you application context and in none of case it will give you "null". You are definetely doing some thning wrong in accessing context.

Comment: I updated my code, please check and share the result.

Comment: Actually my application is build on Android annotation framework I think that is the problem. Are you familiar with Android annotation framework?

Comment: @AwaisNaeem: Sorry dear , i am not aware of this framework. Is code shared by me is not working in your framework ?

Comment: @Rool no 1 Maybe your implementation is right but did not work in annotation framework. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @AwaisNaeem: Accept my answer if you find is correct.